# Dot Notation on JavaScript variables

Tags: javascript

```
dateNow = new Date()
dateGet = dateNow.getDay()
document.write(dateGet.toDateString())
```

Why is this `document.write(date11.toDateString())` not allowed in JavaScript...`date11` is a variable. It gives me an error of "toDateString() is not a function"

Comment: You mean `dateGet` not `date11`, right?

Answer (score 0):

*Presuming you meant to write `dateGet` and not `date11` in your question:*

The problem is that `dateGet` is not a `Date` instance-- it is a *number* that was returned from the `getDay()` `Date` method.

```js
const dateNow = new Date()
const dateGet = dateNow.getDay()

console.log(dateNow instanceof Date); // true
console.log(typeof dateNow.getDay); // function
console.log(dateGet instanceof Date); //false
console.log(typeof dateGet); // number
console.log(typeof dateGet.toDateString); // undefined

document.write(dateGet.toDateString()) //
```

Since `dateGet` is not an instance of `Date` but is actually a number, it has no such method as `.toDateString`, so when you attempt to call this non-existent method an error is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

`toDateString()` is a function for Date objects. dateGet or date11 are actually integers because that's what `getDay()` returns, so that's by design: toDateString() is not a function of **integers**. You can either `document.write(dateGet) and that'll return an integer for the day of the week. If you want "monday" or "tuesday", etc. then you'll need to create a small array of days and match to the dateGet.